# Why Progress_percent of an async long_running_recognize call to google speech-to-text api returns only 0 and 100(when it is done)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

My Code:-

```
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

print(u"Waiting for operation to complete...")

def my_callback(future):
    future.result()

operation.add_done_callback(my_callback)

while (not operation.done()):
     print(operation.metadata.progress_percent)

print(operation.metadata.progress_percent)

response = operation.result()
```

and the output is:-

Waiting for operation to complete...
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
100

[Here is an Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0zcZ.jpg)

Comment: Is it a short audio clip?

Comment: Hello @Brendan, Thanks for replying and sorry for checking your response this late. This audio clip was around 5 minutes in duration and 3 mb in size so yeah it took around 1-2 minutes to do the processing and still it gave only 0 and 100 as the output of progress_percent.

Comment: 18 months later and I'm getting the exact same result as @rohitbharti.